# iPhone: Is it possible to add an action to default copy / paste menu phone wide?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Is it possible to add a special action to default copy / paste menu buttons that shows up on UITextFields phone wide, i.e. that would be available in other applications' text fields?

One use case can be a dictionary application that will allow you to look up words while reading a book in iBooks for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would violate the sandbox security structure of the iOS platform. Therefore I think it's not possible.

Any functionality added by an app would be limited to that app itself.

Comment: that was my guess too. it would be good. maybe someday... thanks for the answer.

Comment: what about services like single-sign-on. e.g. if you have a facebook app and facebook's own app installed on the phone, your app can ask facebook app to login. is it not violating the sandbox structure? sorry if this is off-topic.

Comment: In the openURL case that you mentioned, the app is actually asking the other app to perform a function which it is designed to do. There is no transfer of functionality(executable code, files etc.) from one app to another.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can write and design your own popup, but it won't show up in any other application.